# OSError: Unable to open file (File signature not found) h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, h5py

I am trying to read an h5 file

```py
# Reads the Training data file. However, this just reads the speaker list data required for encoding the targets with scikit-learn block "LabelEncoder".
dataServer = h5py.File('Librispeech_960_train_list.h5', 'r')
sLabels=dataServer['lSpeaker'][:]

encoder_spk = LabelEncoder()
encoder_spk.fit(sLabels)
num_spk_class=np.unique(sLabels).shape[0]
```

**but i get this error :**

```py
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper

  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open

OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
```

I get this OSError and I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [h5py OSError: Unable to open file (File signature not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125758/h5py-oserror-unable-to-open-file-file-signature-not-found)

Comment: Just check if it got downloaded properly or not. You can download it again or simply use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html for loading.

Comment: Where did you get the file from?

Comment: A friend of mine sent it to me